# Using TDS and Glass Mapper classes as Search Models in Lucene

Tags: glass-mapper, lucene, tds

So currently when we use TDS we use Glass and have TDS automatically generate glass models that represent our data templates in Sitecore.  That works well, but when we do search with Lucene using these models, we have to define additional search specific models that define `[IndexField]` attributes on properties so the properties know the name of the index field in lucene.

I was curious if there was a way we can combine this information into the regular glass models that are automatically generated by the T4 Templates.  I would think we wouldn't necessarily want to this for every Property, since some we may never want to search on.

Comment: Have you tried just updating the T4 template to include the `[IndexField]` attribute?

Comment: I agree that was my first thought, but I wanted to see if anyone else has some different approaches that I didn't think of was the primary reason I asked the question.